# No messages match using SUB in Java with ZeroMQ

Tags: java, python, zeromq, jzmq

I'm trying to use Java client with ZeroMQ. When subscribing to any prefix, the Java client matches no messages, although a similar Python client matches messages as expected.

**The Python server**

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5556")

for i in range(100):
    r = "XXX " + i
    socket.send_string(r)

    time.sleep(random.randint(0,10))
```

**The Python client working fine**

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")

zip_filter = "XXX"
socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, zip_filter)

for update_nbr in range(5):
    s = socket.recv_string()
    print(s)
```

**The Java client matching no messages**

```
context = ZMQ.context(1);
subscriber = context.socket(ZMQ.SUB);
subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");

String filter = "XXX";
subscriber.subscribe(filter.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
while (true) {
  String msg = subscriber.recvStr(0, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
  // ...
}
```

Using the above Python server, the Python client matches all messages starting with `XXX` as expected.

Using the same Python server, the Java client **matches no messages**.

Do you have any idea what is wrong with the call to `subscribe()` in the Java client?

Comment: I've recreated your server and clients - both work completely fine. And what is strange, I simply don't have a method recStr(int, Charset). Using subscriber.recvStr() works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've recreated your configuration and sadly, everything works fine - both in python and java. (here's the proof) [image])

Java code:

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Context context = context(1);
        final Socket subscriber = context.socket(SUB);
        subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");

        String filter = "XXX";
        subscriber.subscribe(filter.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        while (true) {
            String msg = subscriber.recvStr();
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.zeromq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jeromq</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

zeromq version: 4.1.0

What version of jeromq do you use? I don't even have a method `recvStr(int, Java.nio.charset.Charset).`

Comment: I'm using the JNI Java bindings of jzmq. I'll try jeromq which I didn't know so far. More later.

Comment: Switching from the c++/JNI Java bindings to jeromq solved the problem. Thanks for the hint! The bounty will follow as soon as I am allowed to award it.