# Network connection to (external) Python server

Tags: java, android, python, sockets, network-programming

I created a Java client, which should connect to a python server. As a standalone it works perfectly fine, connection is established and data will be sending through.

```
public class ClientTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        requestGazeData();
    }

    public static void requestGazeData() {
        ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
        ZMQ.Socket request = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
        request.connect("tcp://xxx.x.x.x:50020");

        // Ask for the sub port
        request.send("SUB_PORT");
        String subPort = request.recvStr();
        System.out.println("subPort: " + subPort);

        // open a sub port to listen to pupil
        ZMQ.Socket subscriber = context.socket(ZMQ.SUB);
        subscriber.connect("tcp://xxx.x.x.x:" + subPort);

        String gaze = "gaze";
        subscriber.subscribe(gaze.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        while (true) {
            String msg = subscriber.recvStr();
            System.out.println(msg);

            subscriber.close();
            context.term();
        }
    }
}
```

Now this client has to run after the app started, but nothing happens. I don't get any data from the server and it get stuck. It is definitely a problem from the Android side, I reckon moreover especially the activity class. This one looks as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set function for button
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ClientTest.requestGazeData();
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

I don't get an exception either. In my `Manifest.xml` I put all needed permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Lastly, I allowed the connection on the ports in my firewall (via ufw in Ubuntu). I've run out of ideas how to fix it and make it work.

**UPDATE:**
Due to the one possible answer I tried the `AsyncTask`, but still anything happens. Here's my updated activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set function for the button
        findViewById(R.id.connectButton).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        new NetworkCall().execute("");
                    }
                });
    }

    private class NetworkCall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            ZMQ.Context context = ZMQ.context(1);
            ZMQ.Socket request = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ);
            request.connect("tcp://xxx.x.x.x:50020");

            System.out.println("Connected");
            // ask for the sub port
            request.send("SUB_PORT");
            String subPort = request.recvStr();
            System.out.println("subPort: " + subPort);

            //int subPortNo = Integer.parseInt(subPort);

            // open a sub port to listen to pupil
            ZMQ.Socket subscriber = context.socket(ZMQ.SUB);
            subscriber.connect("tcp://xxx.x.x.x:" + subPort);

            String gaze = "gaze";
            subscriber.subscribe(gaze.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

            while (true) {
                String msg = subscriber.recvStr();
                System.out.println(msg);

                //subscriber.close();
                //context.term();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Three points for the code safety**: [A] better always set **`LINGER`** to `1` on the **`REQ`** socket right upon instantiation ( to avoid a risk of infinite hangup upon `.term()` ), next, [B] `.close()` it right upon having received the port# and [C] **avoid blocking** `subscriber.revStr()` and rather implement a non-blocking handling in `Poller.poll()`. Almost sure Android system will indeed hate any ( potentially infinitely ) blocking-methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying literally everything, I disabled the firewall and finally the connection worked. Sometimes it can be the small details.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call a function which does a network communication in the main thread in Android. You need to pass this task to an `AsyncTask` and it will just work fine.

Here's an example of an `AsyncTask` which might help you.

```
private class NetworkCall extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Data data = ClientTest.requestGazeData();
        return data.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Do something with your data.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

Now simply start the `AsyncTask` on the click of your `button`.

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new NetworkCall().execute("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I edited my code and added the `AsyncTask`, but unfortunately your solution didn't help.

Comment: Cay you please update your question along with the code that you have now. So that I can check if there's any wrong implementation there.

Comment: Updated my question.